# Add downward arrow to tab menu

Tags: jquery, css, html

Currently I'm working on a simple tab menu and want to display a down arrow when the tab is active .   This is the current code that I'm working with.  I've tried  a few things in jQuery but have had no luck.  CSS seems to be the best way for this to be accomplished.  Am I correct?  How would you accomplish this?

Btw, check out the code in full page view for better styling.

```css
.tab_menu {
  margin: 40px 30px 0 30px;
}
ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: rgba(68, 170, 255, 0.1);
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.tab li {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  /* text-align: center; */
  padding: 14px 9px 14px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(68, 170, 255, 0.5);
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */

ul.tab li a:focus,
.active {
  background-color: rgba(68, 170, 255, 0.9);
}
/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 25px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tab_menu a {
  text-align: center;
}
.triangle-bottom {
  border-top: solid 20px #54b1ff;
  border-left: solid 25px transparent;
  border-right: solid 25px transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 168px;
```

```html
<div class="tab_menu">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'coverage');" id="defaultOpen">Our Coverage</a>
      <div class="triangle-bottom"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'claims')">Common Claims</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'bwc')">Buy With Confidence</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'faq')">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Where should be the down arrow displayed? And how should it look? You have an icon for it?

Comment: I've updated the code to show the arrow below the tab.  It's not exactly how it is on my end but it shows the arrow at least.

Comment: But you failed to mention where exactly the arrow needs to be

Comment: Sorry, this is the what it's supposed to look like:  http://imgur.com/a/1BMcI

Comment: So... did you try just reducing the `margin-left` on your `.triangle-bottom` rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your provided code, just adjusting the left margin did the job

```
.triangle-bottom {
   margin-left: 119px;
}
```

```css
.tab_menu {
  margin: 40px 30px 0 30px;
}
ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: rgba(68, 170, 255, 0.1);
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.tab li {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  /* text-align: center; */
  padding: 14px 9px 14px 9px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(68, 170, 255, 0.5);
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */

ul.tab li a:focus,
.active {
  background-color: rgba(68, 170, 255, 0.9);
}
/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 25px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tab_menu a {
  text-align: center;
}
.triangle-bottom {
  border-top: solid 20px #54b1ff;
  border-left: solid 25px transparent;
  border-right: solid 25px transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 119px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="tab_menu">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'coverage');" id="defaultOpen">Our Coverage</a>
      <div class="triangle-bottom"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'claims')">Common Claims</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'bwc')">Buy With Confidence</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openContent(event, 'faq')">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```